# Querying nested fields with no arrays

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

For the following document "27", and "28" are the days of the current month, while "6" through "11"  under "27" represents hour, I want to be able to retrieve users array only for each hour to do some processing using python, or ideally capture the users array for the whole day, but if I can access users hourly I can do this using python no problem.

```
{
        "values" : {
                "27" : {
                        "6" : {
                                "users" : [
                                        "5b5abc5ddd601f0b6681358a"
                                ],
                                "values" : {
                                        "5b5abc5ddd601f0b6681358a" : 2
                                }
                        },
                        "7" : {
                                "users" : [
                                        "5b5ac75cdd601f0b668157ff",
                                        "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803"
                                ],
                                "values" : {
                                        "5b5ac75cdd601f0b668157ff" : 1,
                                        "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803" : 4
                                }
                        },
                        "8" : {
                                "users" : [
                                        "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803"
                                ],
                                "values" : {
                                        "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803" : 2
                                }
                        },
                        "9" : {
                                "users" : [
                                        "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803",
                                        "5b5ae89b781e011702f00812"
                                ],
                                "values" : {
                                        "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803" : 2,
                                        "5b5ae89b781e011702f00812" : 3
                                }
                        },
                        "10" : {
                                "users" : [
                                        "5b5ae89b781e011702f00812"
                                ],
                                "values" : {
                                        "5b5ae89b781e011702f00812" : 1
                                }
                        }
                },
                "28" : {
                        "11" : {
                                "users" : [
                                        "5b5abacadd601f0b6681312e"
                                ],
                                "values" : {
                                        "5b5abacadd601f0b6681312e" : 1
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The thing is because there are no arrays here, so unwinding doesn't work, also there are days and hours where there were no activity so there's no data available for them.

Comment: What would be the expected output for this model ?

Comment: I mean how would you like to transform pasted document using MongoDB

Comment: I want to have it as {day: [users]} {"27": ["5b5abc5ddd601f0b6681358a","5b5ac75cdd601f0b668157ff","5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803","5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803","5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803","5b5ae89b781e011702f00812","5b5ae89b781e011702f00812"]}

Comment: {"28": ["5b5abacadd601f0b6681312e"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to work with dynamic key names. Then you can apply [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) combined with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to flatten your data model and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get a result with days as keys:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            days: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$values" },
                    as: "day",
                    in: {
                        k: "$$day.k",
                        v: {
                            $map: { 
                                input: { $objectToArray: "$$day.v" },
                                as: "h",
                                in: {
                                    $map: {
                                        input: { $objectToArray: "$$h.v.values" },
                                        as: "pair",
                                        in: "$$pair.k"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            days: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$days",
                        as: "day",
                        in: {
                            k: "$$day.k",
                            v: {
                                $reduce: {
                                    input: "$$day.v",
                                    initialValue: [],
                                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "days" : {
            "27" : [
                    "5b5ae89b781e011702f00812",
                    "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803",
                    "5b5ae89b781e011702f00812",
                    "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803",
                    "5b5ac75cdd601f0b668157ff",
                    "5b5acd0ddd601f0b66816803",
                    "5b5abc5ddd601f0b6681358a"
            ],
            "28" : [
                    "5b5abacadd601f0b6681312e"
            ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius!
Thank you.